# R: data.table cross-join not working

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two `data.table`s that I want to join (form a Cartesian product of). One of the `data.table`s is keyed on a `Date` vector, and the other on a `numeric` vector:

```
# data.table with dates (as numeric)
dtDates2 = data.table(date = 
                       as.numeric(seq(from = as.Date('2014/01/01'), 
                           to = as.Date('2014/07/01'), by = 'weeks')),
                     data1 = rnorm(26))

# data.table with dates
dtDates1 = data.table(date = 
                        seq(from = as.Date('2014/01/01'), 
                            to = as.Date('2014/07/01'), by = 'weeks'),
                      data1 = rnorm(26))


# data.table with customer IDs
dtCustomers = data.table(customerID = seq(1, 100),
                      data2 = rnorm(100))
```

I `setkey` and try to cross-join them using `CJ`:

```
# cross join the two datatables
setkey(dtCustomers, customerID)
setkey(dtDates1, date)
setkey(dtDates2, date)

CJ(dtCustomers, dtDates1)
CJ(dtCustomers, dtDates2)
```

but get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  Invalid column: it has dimensions. Can't format it. If it's the result of data.table(table()), use as.data.table(table()) instead.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The error message clearly tells you that you can't cross join data.tables, you can only do it on vectors (columns). `?CJ` will tell you the same. What are you trying to achieve? Are you just trying to merge these data.tables?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I am. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Based on what fields? I don't see any common columns between `dtCustomers` and the other two data sets

Comment: @DavidArenburg Let me update the question to be more clear about what I want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no cross join functionality available in `data.table` out of the box.
Yet there is `CJ.dt` function (a `CJ` like but designed for data.tables) to achieve cartesian product (cross join) available in `optiRum` package (available in CRAN).
You can create the function:

```r
CJ.dt = function(X,Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X),is.data.table(Y))
  k = NULL
  X = X[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(X, k)
  Y = Y[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(Y, NULL)
  X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, k := NULL][]
}
CJ.dt(dtCustomers, dtDates1)
CJ.dt(dtCustomers, dtDates2)
```

Yet there is a FR for convenience way to perform cross join filled in [data.table#1717](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1717), so you could check there if there is a nicer api for cross join.

Answer (score 3):

thank you jangorecki for the very useful function

I had to add support for empty X and/or Y:

```
CJ.dt = function(X, Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X), is.data.table(Y))

  if(nrow(X) > 0 & nrow(Y) > 0){
    k = NULL
    X = X[, c(k = 1, .SD)]
    setkey(X, k)
    Y = Y[, c(k = 1, .SD)]
    setkey(Y, NULL)
    return(X[Y, allow.cartesian = T][, k := NULL][])

  } else {
    duplicatedNames <- names(Y)[names(Y) %in% names(X)]
    if(length(duplicatedNames) > 0) {
       setnames(Y, duplicatedNames, paste0("i.", duplicatedNames))
    }
    setkey(Y)
    setkey(X)
    return(cbind(X[!X], Y[!Y]))
  }

}

# X <- data.table(a = c(1, 2))
# Y <- data.table(a = c(2, 3), b = c(4, 5))
#
# CJ.dt(X, Y)

# CJ.dt(X[a > 2], Y)
```