# R Cartesian product of two data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.frames here described.

```
Table1
ID  AMOUNT  ATTRIBUTE_2
K.20141107.003  1   DACH
K.20141127.048  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141107.003  0,35    E_INTRA
K.20141127.048  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141107.003  0,03    CCP

Table2
ID  MONTH   M_VALUE ATTRIBUTE_1 CLOSE_DATE
K.20141127.048  01.01.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.02.2015  0,076712329 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.03.2015  0,084817352 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.04.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.05.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.06.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.07.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.08.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.09.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.10.2015  0,085045662 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.11.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141127.048  01.12.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014
K.20141107.003  01.11.2014  1   IN  01.11.2014
```

I would like to merge the two tables over the ID and get a cartesian product of the tables based on (ID, ATTRIBUTE_2) in Table1 and (ID, MONTH) in Table2.

I tried the following which is not working:

```
TABLE1[ , merge(TABLE1, TABLE2, by = "ID", all = FALSE), by = "ATTRIBUTE2"]
```

The result I am tring to get is the following:

```
ID  MONTH   M_VALUE ATTRIBUTE_1 CLOSE_DATE  AMOUNT  ATTRIBUTE_2
K.20141127.048  01.01.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.02.2015  0,076712329 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.03.2015  0,084817352 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.04.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.05.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.06.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.07.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.08.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.09.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.10.2015  0,085045662 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.11.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.12.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  197,1   E_FUT
K.20141127.048  01.01.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.02.2015  0,076712329 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.03.2015  0,084817352 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.04.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.05.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.06.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.07.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.08.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.09.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.10.2015  0,085045662 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.11.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.12.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  30  F1BY
K.20141127.048  01.01.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.02.2015  0,076712329 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.03.2015  0,084817352 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.04.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.05.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.06.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.07.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.08.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.09.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.10.2015  0,085045662 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.11.2015  0,082191781 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141127.048  01.12.2015  0,084931507 MATT    01.11.2014  131,4   ECC_E
K.20141107.003  01.11.2014  1   IN  01.11.2014  1   DACH
K.20141107.003  01.11.2014  1   IN  01.11.2014  0,35    E_INTRA
K.20141107.003  01.11.2014  1   IN  01.11.2014  0,03    CCP
```

Please notice as ID K.20141127.048 gets duplicated 12 times per each combination of (ID, ATTRIBUTE_2) in TABLE1.
I can solve this over a for loop but I would prefer a more elegant solution. Anybody an idea how to get the final result?

Comment: Use full_join in dplyr

Comment: Hi, I am just checking but I think merge(Table1, Table1, allow.cartesian = TRUE) should do the job.

Comment: It worked with merge(Table1, Table1, allow.cartesian = TRUE). The condition allow.cartesian was the point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should use the word **data.table** in your question (and not 'data.frame'). ... and also set the tag `data.table`.

Comment: @adiana full join is not a cartesian product. ddg feel free to self-answer your question, next time remember about reproducible example

Comment: Or, you know, use Jan's function, if that's what you're after http://stackoverflow.com/a/27347397/1191259