# Count matching elements by row between two data tables in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, data.table, match

I have two data frames in R, and I need to count the element matches row by row, getting finally a column with the length of the cartesian product of both tables and the IDs of both rows. Also, the tables are quite big and with different number of rows, but same number of columns.

I have the following code, but it is quite slow when having multiple runs.

```
library(data.table)

table_1<-data.table(matrix(c(1:24),nrow = 4))
table_2<-data.table(matrix(c(11:34),nrow = 4))

names(table_1)<-c("s1", "s2","s3","s4","s5","s6")
names(table_2)<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")

table_1$ID<-seq.int(nrow(table_1))
table_2$ID_ap<-seq.int(nrow(table_2))

setcolorder(table_1, c("ID", "s1", "s2","s3","s4","s5","s6"))
setcolorder(table_2, c("ID_ap","a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6"))

CJ.table<-function(X,Y) setkey(X[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[Y[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL] 

join<-CJ.table(table_1,table_2)

R<-subset(join, select=c("ID_ap","ID"))

R$Ac<- (join$s1 == join$a1) + (join$s1 ==join$a2) + (join$s1 ==join$a3) + (join$s1 ==join$a4) + (join$s1 ==join$a5) + (join$s1 ==join$a6)+ 
(join$s2 == join$a1) + (join$s2 ==join$a2) + (join$s2 ==join$a3) + (join$s2 ==join$a4) + (join$s2 ==join$a5) + (join$s2 ==join$a6)+ 
(join$s3 == join$a1) + (join$s3 ==join$a2) + (join$s3 ==join$a3) + (join$s3 ==join$a4) + (join$s3 ==join$a5) + (join$s3 ==join$a6)+ 
(join$s4 == join$a1) + (join$s4 ==join$a2) + (join$s4 ==join$a3) + (join$s4 ==join$a4) + (join$s4 ==join$a5) + (join$s4 ==join$a6)+ 
(join$s5 == join$a1) + (join$s5 ==join$a2) + (join$s5 ==join$a3) + (join$s5 ==join$a4) + (join$s5 ==join$a5) + (join$s5 ==join$a6)+ 
(join$s6 == join$a1) + (join$s6 ==join$a2) + (join$s6 ==join$a3) + (join$s6 ==join$a4) + (join$s6 ==join$a5) + (join$s6 ==join$a6)
```

which gives

```
   R
   ID_ap ID Ac
 1:     1  1  0
 2:     1  2  0
 3:     1  3  4
 4:     1  4  0
 5:     2  1  0
 6:     2  2  0
 7:     2  3  0
 8:     2  4  4
 9:     3  1  3
10:     3  2  0
11:     3  3  0
12:     3  4  0
13:     4  1  0
14:     4  2  3
15:     4  3  0
16:     4  4  0
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of your "data.frame"s and what values do they contain?

Comment: There are around 10k row and a 100 row matrices, filled with small non-zero positive integers.

Comment: Within a row, values are always distinct?

Comment: Yes, values are always distinct within a row, and rows are always distinct within a matrix. But between the two matrices there could be equal rows @Frank

Comment: Regarding your CJ.table, you might be interested in this this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25888706

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the data in long format, since the column order does not matter:

```
setnames(table_2, "ID_ap", "ID")
tabs = rbind(
  melt(table_1, id="ID")[, variable := NULL],
  melt(table_2, id="ID")[, variable := NULL],
  idcol = TRUE)
```

(1) For each value, identify relevant pairs; and

(2) for pairs, count values:

```
tabs[, 
  if (uniqueN(.id) > 1L) CJ(ID1 = ID[.id == 1L], ID2 = ID[.id == 2L])
, by=value][,
   .N
, by=.(ID1, ID2)]


   ID1 ID2 N
1:   3   1 4
2:   4   2 4
3:   1   3 3
4:   2   4 3
```

All other `(ID1, ID2)` combos are zero and need not be explicitly enumerated, I think.

---

---

If values are *distinct within each table*, as in the OP's example, then we can simplify:

```
tabs[, if (.N==2L) .(ID1 = ID[1L], ID2 = ID[2L]), by=value][, .N, by=.(ID1, ID2)]
```

Comment: a simple join can reconstruct the zeros if OP needs them

Comment: Nice, this beats the (already kinda fast) OP's code -- I looked at the timings in my answer (which included a slow base R solution):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36558985/4598520

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the product of the number of rows and the number of unique values in both tables is not large:

```
x1 = unlist(table_1, FALSE, FALSE)
x2 = unlist(table_2, FALSE, FALSE)
```

with common unique values:

```
lvs = union(x1, x2)
```

And `tabulate` the occurence of each unique value in each row for each table:

```
tab1 = matrix(tabulate(seq_len(nrow(table_1)) + (match(x1, lvs) - 1L) * nrow(table_1), 
                       nrow(table_1) * length(lvs)), 
              nrow(table_1), length(lvs))
tab2 = matrix(tabulate(seq_len(nrow(table_2)) + (match(x2, lvs) - 1L) * nrow(table_2), 
                       nrow(table_2) * length(lvs)), 
              nrow(table_2), length(lvs))
```

finally:

```
tcrossprod(tab1, tab2) #or 'tcrossprod(tab1 > 0L, tab2 > 0L)' to not count duplicate matches
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    3    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    3
#[3,]    4    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    4    0    0

#and to change format (among different ways):
ans = tcrossprod(tab1, tab2)
cbind(c(row(ans)), c(col(ans)), c(ans))
```

If `tab1` and `tab2` are very large, they can be built as sparse matrices and a way could be:

```
library(Matrix)
stab1 = xtabs(rep_len(1L, length(x1)) ~ 
                    rep_len(seq_len(nrow(table_1)), length(x1)) 
                    + factor(match(x1, lvs), lvs), 
              sparse = TRUE)
stab2 = xtabs(rep_len(1L, length(x2)) ~ 
                    rep_len(seq_len(nrow(table_2)), length(x2)) 
                    + factor(match(x2, lvs), lvs), 
              sparse = TRUE)
tcrossprod(stab1, stab2)
#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#  1 2 3 4
#1 . . 3 .
#2 . . . 3
#3 4 . . .
#4 . 4 . .
```

**EDIT**

Having (1) small positive integer values and (2) distinct values in each row, creating lookups with `match`/`unique`/`union` and tabulating can be avoided:

```
x1 = unlist(table_1, FALSE, FALSE)
x2 = unlist(table_2, FALSE, FALSE)
nlvs = max(max(x1), max(x2))
stab1 = sparseMatrix(i = rep_len(seq_len(nrow(table_1)), length(x1)), 
                     j = x1, 
                     x = 1L, 
                     dims = c(nrow(table_1), nlvs))
stab2 = sparseMatrix(i = rep_len(seq_len(nrow(table_2)), length(x2)), 
                     j = x2, 
                     x = 1L, 
                     dims = c(nrow(table_2), nlvs))
tcrossprod(stab1, stab2)
#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#            
#[1,] . . 3 .
#[2,] . . . 3
#[3,] 4 . . .
#[4,] . 4 . .

summary(tcrossprod(stab1, stab2))
#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 4 entries 
#  i j x
#1 3 1 4
#2 4 2 4
#3 1 3 3
#4 2 4 3
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
colSums(apply(join[, !c("ID", "ID_ap"), with = F], 1, duplicated))
#[1] 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
```

Or, starting from scratch:

```
setkey(table_1, ID)
setkey(table_2, ID_ap)

ids = CJ(ID1 = table_1$ID, ID2 = table_2$ID_ap)
ids[, sum(duplicated(c(table_1[.(ID1), !'ID', with = F],
                       table_2[.(ID2), !'ID_ap', with = F])))
    , by = .(ID1, ID2)]
#    ID1 ID2 V1
# 1:   1   1  0
# 2:   1   2  0
# 3:   1   3  3
# 4:   1   4  0
# 5:   2   1  0
# 6:   2   2  0
# 7:   2   3  0
# 8:   2   4  3
# 9:   3   1  4
#10:   3   2  0
#11:   3   3  0
#12:   3   4  0
#13:   4   1  0
#14:   4   2  4
#15:   4   3  0
#16:   4   4  0
```

Answer (score 2):

The performance requirements aren't clearly stated in the post. But, I've created a larger version of your reproducible example (below) and the code in the question is pretty fast already.

Here's how to do it in base R, for good measure:

```
t1 <- as.data.frame(table_1)
t2 <- as.data.frame(table_2)

system.time({
  ## compute all combinations of indices
  indices <- merge(t1[1], t2[1])

  ## create a mega df including all rows, cbinded together
  rows <- cbind(t1[indices[ ,"ID"], -1], t2[indices[ , "ID_ap"], -1])

  t1_cols <- names(rows) %in% names(t1)
  t2_cols <- names(rows) %in% names(t2)

  ## compute the counts; this step takes most of the time
  ## ~ 14 of the 18 second in this example
  counts <- apply(rows, 1, function(r) sum(r[t1_cols] %in% r[t2_cols]))
})
out <- data.frame(indices, Ac=counts)
```

For example, for the large reproducible problem from below (`dim(out) == c(1e6, 3)`), the above code runs in less than 20 seconds.

```
   user  system elapsed
 17.879   0.348  18.245
```

**Edit** Large reproducible problem:

```
library(data.table)
NROW <- 1e4
NROW2 <- 1e2
table_1<-data.table(matrix(c(1:24),nrow = NROW, ncol=6))
table_2<-data.table(matrix(c(11:34),nrow = NROW2, ncol=6))

names(table_1)<-c("s1", "s2","s3","s4","s5","s6")
names(table_2)<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")

table_1$ID<-seq.int(nrow(table_1))
table_2$ID_ap<-seq.int(nrow(table_2))

setcolorder(table_1, c("ID", "s1", "s2","s3","s4","s5","s6"))
setcolorder(table_2, c("ID_ap","a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6"))
```

The OP's solution runs *much* faster than this answer

```
CJ.table<-function(X,Y) setkey(X[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[Y[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL] 

join<-CJ.table(table_1,table_2)

R<-subset(join, select=c("ID_ap","ID"))

system.time({
   R$Ac<- (join$s1 == join$a1) + (join$s1 ==join$a2) + (join$s1 ==join$a3) + (join$s1 ==join$a4) + (join$s1 ==join$a5) + (join$s1 ==join$a6)+
  (join$s2 == join$a1) + (join$s2 ==join$a2) + (join$s2 ==join$a3) + (join$s2 ==join$a4) + (join$s2 ==join$a5) + (join$s2 ==join$a6)+
  (join$s3 == join$a1) + (join$s3 ==join$a2) + (join$s3 ==join$a3) + (join$s3 ==join$a4) + (join$s3 ==join$a5) + (join$s3 ==join$a6)+
  (join$s4 == join$a1) + (join$s4 ==join$a2) + (join$s4 ==join$a3) + (join$s4 ==join$a4) + (join$s4 ==join$a5) + (join$s4 ==join$a6)+
  (join$s5 == join$a1) + (join$s5 ==join$a2) + (join$s5 ==join$a3) + (join$s5 ==join$a4) + (join$s5 ==join$a5) + (join$s5 ==join$a6)+
  (join$s6 == join$a1) + (join$s6 ==join$a2) + (join$s6 ==join$a3) + (join$s6 ==join$a4) + (join$s6 ==join$a5) + (join$s6 ==join$a6)
})
#    user  system elapsed
# 0.295   0.044   0.339
```

but the solution in Frank's answer is faster still

```
setnames(table_2, "ID_ap", "ID")
tabs = rbind(
               melt(table_1, id="ID")[, variable := NULL],
                 melt(table_2, id="ID")[, variable := NULL],
                 idcol = TRUE)

system.time({out3 <- tabs[,
        if (uniqueN(.id) > 1L) CJ(ID1 = ID[.id == 1L], ID2 = ID[.id == 2L])
        , by=value][,
           .N
        , by=.(ID1, ID2)]})
#   user  system elapsed
#  0.109   0.013   0.122
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a benchmark. I was hoping someone would. I'd be curious to see if any of the others perform well, too. It's hard to know what to include/exclude in the `system.time()` call. I would argue that my `tabs` creation belongs outside (as you have it here) because the data should be stored in that way to begin with. But the OP's creation of `join` and `R` belong inside the call, since they are part of the process just for this computation (but they are outside the call here). It's pretty subjective, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm impressed with your answer, and want to learn some `data.table` now. I also agree about the subjectivity.

Comment: If we put the OP's `join` and `R` in `system.time` that bumps user time up to `0.590`. I tried @eddi 's `colSums` line too, and it's almost as slow as mine (`user = `10.581`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
> t1<-data.frame(matrix(c(1:24),nrow = 4))
> t2<-data.frame(matrix(c(11:34),nrow = 4))
> ret<-expand.grid(r1=1:nrow(t1),r2=1:nrow(t2))
> ret$matches<-apply(ret,1,function(a)sum(t1[a[1],] %in% t2[a[2],]))
> ret
   r1 r2 matches
1   1  1       0
2   2  1       0
3   3  1       4
4   4  1       0
5   1  2       0
6   2  2       0
7   3  2       0
8   4  2       4
9   1  3       3
10  2  3       0
11  3  3       0
12  4  3       0
13  1  4       0
14  2  4       3
15  3  4       0
16  4  4       0
```

Comment: thanks @mrip, works fine with small matrices, but it's taking much longer than the original code when using bigger ones like 10k rows, i'll try take a look deeper on it.

Comment: If you have a big dataset and need speed I would recommend (1) don't use data.frame or data.table, but just use matrices and (2) use Rcpp to write a more efficient matcher.