# Merge two data.tables where all rows in dt2 are combined with each row in dt1

Tags: r, data.table

I have data similar to this except `dt1` has **29 million** rows and `dt2` has **only 15 rows (not 15 million)**.

```
dt1 <- data.table(ID=1:4,City=c("Charlotte","DC","Salem","Boston"))
dt2 <- data.table(Birds=c("Saker","Peregrine","Barbary","Prarie","Golden","Coopers","Canary","Finch"),BirdType=c("Falcon","Falcon","Falcon","Falcon","Eagle","Hawk","Breakfast","Breakfast"))
```

Which outputs like this:

```
> dt1
   ID      City
1:  1 Charlotte
2:  2        DC
3:  3     Salem
4:  4    Boston

> dt2
       Birds  BirdType
1:     Saker    Falcon
2: Peregrine    Falcon
3:   Barbary    Falcon
4:    Prarie    Falcon
5:    Golden     Eagle
6:   Coopers      Hawk
7:    Canary Breakfast
8:     Finch Breakfast
```

I would like to merge the two data.tables whereby each row of dt1 is combined with all rows of dt2, ultimately giving a data.table with 32 rows with output like this:

```
> dtMerged
   ID      City  Birds     BirdType
1:  1  Charlotte Saker      Falcon
2:  1  Charlotte Peregrine  Falcon
3:  1  Charlotte Barbary    Falcon
4:  1  Charlotte Prarie     Falcon
5:  1  Charlotte Golden     Eagle   
6:  1  Charlotte Coopers    Hawk
7:  1  Charlotte Canary   Breakfast
8:  1  Charlotte Finch    Breakfast
9:   2        DC Saker      Falcon
10:  2        DC Peregrine  Falcon
11:  2        DC Barbary    Falcon
12:  2        DC Prarie     Falcon
13:  2        DC Golden     Eagle   
14:  2        DC Coopers    Hawk
15:  2        DC Canary   Breakfast
16:  2        DC Finch    Breakfast
17:  3     Salem Saker      Falcon
18:  3     Salem Saker      Falcon
etc...
```

Any ideas on how best to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.
I am using `data.table` version 1.10.4 on a Windows 7 PC.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use `CJ` to do a cross join i.e. `CJ(do.call(paste, c(dt1, sep=",")), do.call(paste, c(dt2, sep=",")))[, unlist(lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, split = ","), recursive = FALSE)]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  Cross join is the way to go.

Comment: `dt1[, as.list(dt2), by=names(dt1)]` also seems to work. Oh, or maybe do it the other way around since dt2 has so many fewer rows in your real use-case. Also, if each bird name is unique, you could keep these two smaller tables and just make a new one only containing Birds and ID, saving somewhat on memory: `CJ(ID = dt1$ID, BirdName = dt2$Birds)`. Then you could just look up the city from ID and the bird type from name as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: data.table cross-join not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888706/r-data-table-cross-join-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun commented, cross join seems to be one of the ways to solve the problem. To implement it, I referenced a really neat function by @jangorecki `CJ.dt` in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888706/r-data-table-cross-join-not-working) to get to the desired solution:

```
CJ.dt = function(X,Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X),is.data.table(Y))
  k = NULL
  X = X[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(X, k)
  Y = Y[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(Y, NULL)
  X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, k := NULL][]
}

new_df <- CJ.dt(dt1, dt2)
setorder(new_df, ID)
```

Here is what the complete output looks like, after re-ordering:

```
> new_df

 ID      City     Birds  BirdType
 1:  1 Charlotte     Saker    Falcon
 2:  1 Charlotte Peregrine    Falcon
 3:  1 Charlotte   Barbary    Falcon
 4:  1 Charlotte    Prarie    Falcon
 5:  1 Charlotte    Golden     Eagle
 6:  1 Charlotte   Coopers      Hawk
 7:  1 Charlotte    Canary Breakfast
 8:  1 Charlotte     Finch Breakfast
 9:  2        DC     Saker    Falcon
10:  2        DC Peregrine    Falcon
11:  2        DC   Barbary    Falcon
12:  2        DC    Prarie    Falcon
13:  2        DC    Golden     Eagle
14:  2        DC   Coopers      Hawk
15:  2        DC    Canary Breakfast
16:  2        DC     Finch Breakfast
17:  3     Salem     Saker    Falcon
18:  3     Salem Peregrine    Falcon
19:  3     Salem   Barbary    Falcon
20:  3     Salem    Prarie    Falcon
21:  3     Salem    Golden     Eagle
22:  3     Salem   Coopers      Hawk
23:  3     Salem    Canary Breakfast
24:  3     Salem     Finch Breakfast
25:  4    Boston     Saker    Falcon
26:  4    Boston Peregrine    Falcon
27:  4    Boston   Barbary    Falcon
28:  4    Boston    Prarie    Falcon
29:  4    Boston    Golden     Eagle
30:  4    Boston   Coopers      Hawk
31:  4    Boston    Canary Breakfast
32:  4    Boston     Finch Breakfast
```

Comment: Thanks so much @david-c.  This worked perfectly and quickly on my larger data set.