# Use loop or apply command to calculate U statistics in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am thinking of using a loop or apply command to solve this problem but failed.
[image: formula for reference]

[image: description for U statistics]

Comment: `ifelse(A>B, 1, 0)`? Also, it's useful to state the problem in a general sense (in which you would have found an answer with a Google search), provide a dataset, and provide a desired output.

Comment: What exactly did you try? How exactly did it fail? This is not a specific programming question right now.

Comment: @AndrewPruet; MrFlick  I attached the description then. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a data.table, the solution can be found with the aid of the CJ.dt function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347397/5744762). Below is what I think you are looking for with the limited description you provided.

```
library(data.table)

#Create sample datasets
DT_tor <- data.table(ID = 1:100, time_tor = abs(rnorm(100)))
DT_bunny <- data.table(ID = 1:100, time_bunny = abs(rnorm(100)))

#CJ.dt function
CJ.dt = function(X,Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X),is.data.table(Y))
  k = NULL
  X = X[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(X, k)
  Y = Y[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(Y, NULL)
  X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, k := NULL][]
}

#Crossjoin two data.tables
DT_CJ <- CJ.dt(DT_tor, DT_bunny)

#Get a score for the tortoise and a score for the bunny
Score_tor <- DT_CJ[time_tor < time_bunny, .N]
Score_bunny <- DT_CJ[time_tor > time_bunny, .N]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.But what if I have existing data for Hare and Tortoise, how should I change then?

Comment: @SuxiZheng You should have provided a sample of the existing data in the question like I asked... Also, there is a plethora of resources out there to figure out how to do what you are asking. You need to at least put some effort into solving the question on your own.

Comment: OK I see!Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SuxiZheng If this solution works for you, please accept this as an answer, otherwise, please restate the question so it can be answered.