# How to conditionally summarize on other entries in the group - R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rcpp

In my dataset I have Cartesian coordinates of different items overtime identified by an EventID, event_type, ID number, x position, y position, identity type, broad category, and frame id number. What I need to do is go for each EventID, event_type pair, and frame id number go through each ID number and calculate which other ID number with a different broad category has the minimum distance from the current row. I would like to avoid using for loops for this because the dataset is several million lines long.

I tried formulating this as a group_by and summarize call using dplyr but couldn't quite wrap my head around how I could call a function on the current row x, an y against all other x, and ys and then choose the conditional minimum.

```
two_dim_euclid = function(x1, x2, y1, y2){
  a <- sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
  return(a)
}


# Example Data
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 EventID = c(1003, 1003, 1003, 1003),
                 event_type = c(893, 893, 893, 893),
                 ID_number = c(80427, 2346, 24954, 27765),
                 x = c(86.07, 72.4, 43.08, 80.13),
                 y = c(35.58, 26.43, 34.8, 34.79),
                 identity_type = c("A", "C", "B", "B"),
                 broad_category = c("set1", "set1", "set2", "set2"),
                 frame_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
df
#  EventID event_type ID_number x     y     identity_type broad_category frame_id
#1 1003    893        80427     86.07 35.58 A             set1           1
#2 1003    893        2346      72.40 26.43 C             set1           1
#3 1003    893        24954     43.08 34.80 B             set2           1
#4 1003    893        27765     80.13 34.79 B             set2           1
```

The expected result would return 5.992303 for row 1 it looks for all the entries not belonging to set1 with the same EventID, event_type, and frame_id and then returns the minimum euclidian distance given those parameters.

Also, I want to do this for every entry with identity type A. But, the identity_type and broad_category are not always tied together. A can belong to either set1 or set2.

Comment: Why would it just be 5.992303 (only comparing row 4) and not 5.992303 + 42.997075 (rows 4 AND 3)? Please redefine your criteria for comparison, it's not very easy to follow.

Comment: Because I don't want all the possible distances, only the minimum of the euclidean distances.

Comment: Change the sum in my equation to a min

Comment: I did, works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure about your criteria, it seems that you MUST use for loops in some way if you want to iterate. I'm sure others can provide you with Rcpp solutions that are very quick. In the meantime, here is one possible way with base R.

```
# In the future, please provide the code to create your example data
dat <- structure(list(EventID = c(1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L), 
                  event_type = c(893L, 893L, 893L, 893L), 
                  ID_number = c(80427L, 2346L, 24954L, 27765L), 
                  x = c(86.07, 72.4, 43.08, 80.13), 
                  y = c(35.58, 26.43, 34.8, 34.79), 
                  identity_type = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
                                            .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                                            class = "factor"), 
                  broad_category = structure(c(1L,  1L, 2L, 2L), 
                                             .Label = c("set1", "set2"), 
                                             class = "factor"), 
                  frame_id = c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L)), 
             .Names = c("EventID", "event_type", "ID_number","x", "y", 
                        "identity_type", "broad_category", "frame_id"), 
             class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

# Define your criteria here
dat$uniqueID <- paste0(dat$EventID, dat$event_type, dat$frame_id, dat$broad_category)
# made your function have two 2 dim vectors instead since that's simpler for passing in
two_dim_euclid = function(a, b) return(sqrt((a[1] - b[1])^2 + (a[2] - b[2])^2))

n <- nrow(dat)
vec <- numeric(n)
for(i in 1:n){
  vec[i] = sum(apply(dat[dat$uniqueID != dat$uniqueID[i], c("x","y")], 1, 
                     function(r) two_dim_euclid(dat[i,c("x","y")], r)), na.rm = T)
  if(i%%10000 == 0) cat(i,"completed...\n") # Progress check since >1mil rows
}
dat$result <- vec
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I took your solution and modified it a bit to the following.

'foreach(i = 1:n) %dopar% etc'

and it completes each unique set in about 3 seconds. At that rate in 12 hours I should have everything I need thanks to you! Looked like I would be waiting much longer

Comment: Sean, that is much too long to have to wait! can I recommend creating a second dataframe consisting of ONLY the `uniqueID` and the `x` & `y` columns? this should marginally improve speed. I'm glad you got some parallel stuff working. If this answer was satisfactory for you please mark it as so to close the question. I would advise you add the `Rcpp` label and leave it open for a bit longer though, or even for a `data.table` answer.

Comment: That's fair and will do. I did trim off the unneeded columns before letting it go, figured any marginal improvement was good. Only left what I will need on the back end to match. I'll add the Rcpp lable though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base way that relies on `dist()`.

```
res <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(df$x, df$y)))
res[res == 0] <- Inf

apply(res, 1, min)

        1         2         3         4 
 5.992303 11.386066 30.491299  5.992303 

# or potentially  more performant
res[cbind(seq_len(nrow(res)), max.col(-res))]

[1]  5.992303 11.386066 30.491299  5.992303
```

A potential way with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) would be to do a cartesian join but it would need a lot of memory and would likely be slower:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, ID := .I]

CJ.dt = function(X,Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X),is.data.table(Y))
  k = NULL
  X = X[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(X, k)
  Y = Y[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(Y, NULL)
  X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, k := NULL][]
}
CJ.dt(dt, dt)[ID != i.ID, min(sqrt((x - i.x)^2 + (y-i.y)^2)), by = i.ID]

   i.ID        V1
1:    1  5.992303
2:    2 11.386066
3:    3 30.491299
4:    4  5.992303
```

For data.table cartesian join, see here:
[R: data.table cross-join not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888706/r-data-table-cross-join-not-working/27347397)