# Combining two independent data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables. One contains data about persons (`DT`) and the other one data about items (`DT2`). They don't share any variables, but I would like to combine both of them, so that each row of `DT` is combined with the whole data.table `DT2`. The combinded data.table therefore should be `nrow(DT) * nrow(DT2)` long.

I have an easy solution using `lapply()`, but it doesn't seem very efficient (especially for large data.tables) and I was wondering if there is a more data.table-way to do it.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(
  id = 1:3,
  value = rnorm(3)
)

DT2 <- data.table(
  id2 = 1:2,
  value2 = sample(1:10, 2)
)

# desired output
out <- rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(DT), function(r) {
  cbind(DT[r, ], DT2)
}))

out

   id      value id2 value2
1:  1 -0.6264538   1      7
2:  1 -0.6264538   2      2
3:  2  0.1836433   1      7
4:  2  0.1836433   2      2
5:  3 -0.8356286   1      7
6:  3 -0.8356286   2      2
```

Comment: Do you need `cbind.fill(DT, DT2)`

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [data.table cross-join not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25888706/903061)

Comment: Or, if your `id` columns are unique keys, something like `DT[CJ(id = DT$id, id2 = DT2$id2), on = "id"][DT2, on = "id2"]`

Comment: @akrun `cbind.fill()` only fills up the longer of the two data.table, but does not add new rows.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you for the link and your solution. They both work fine and the solution in the link does not rely on an id variable, so it is a nice general solution. I did not think about looking for cross-joins .